# Two different AWS applications on the same domain with a different subfolders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

Based on this issue [CAS server cross subdomain ST ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364311/cas-server-cross-subdomain-st-ticket) I'm thinking about changing of my applications urls.

I have two applications on the following subdomains

`https://ui.example.com` - static AngularJS application(JavaScript, HTML) hosted on Amazon S3

`https://api.example.com` - Java Spring application hosted on Amazon EC2 instances (for Tomcat) with Elastic Load Balancing that distributes incoming application traffic across multiple Amazon EC2.

Right now I need to change urls of my applications to the following:

```
https://ui.example.com
https://ui.example.com/api
```

In other words I need to make `api.example.com` application available as `/api` subfolder of my `ui.example.com` domain.

How it can be configured with AWS ? Where at AWS I need to make an appropriate changes and configuration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could setup an Nginx proxy in front of both servers, mapping the root path to S3 and the /api path to your EC2 instance. Or you could set up a CloudFront distribution (or use another CDN like CloudFlare) and map the different paths to different origin servers.

In general you have to put a proxy in front of all the servers sharing a domain name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible with Amazon Route 53 ?

Comment: @alexanoid No, that question gets asked on here all the time. Route 53 is just a DNS service. DNS only manages the mapping of domain names. You need something that manages mapping the entire URL path.

Comment: So, in order to use AWS products, CloudFront distribution looks like a more logical choice ? Is any drawbacks of this solution for current task ?

Comment: Well you would be enabling a full CDN when you use CloudFront, so be aware of all the issues that caching your services may entail. CloudFront is going to be fairly expensive. Using a CDN also comes with many advantages though.

Comment: Another option could be AWS API Gateway (https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) that can map a URL to any endpoint. It also supports custom domain names: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

Comment: @Evgeny Goldin, thanks. According to the provided documentation Amazon CloudFront distribution is also involved in this process, isn't it? Another question - is it possible to use the same domain name(for example ui.example.com) that is already pointed to Amazon S3 also for my API application on Amazon EC2 via AWS API Gateway but to a different folder, for example ui.example.com/api ?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to map every endpoint (every page or image URL) on API gateway as a separate endpoint? API gateway also makes certain things more difficult, such as inspecting HTTP headers or returning 30x redirect codes. I don't think API gateway is a good fit here.

Comment: That's correct, API Gateway creates a Cloudfront distribution, here's a forum thread with some more details: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=677382. No, if a custom domain is used for an API gateway endpoint - it'll be CNAMEd to a Cloudfront distribution (see "6. Text similar to the following will appear in the console").

Comment: I assume "ui.example.com" is aliased to an S3 bucket in Route 53. I don't see an option to send "ui.example.com/api" to your ELB in this case. As long as you absolutely have to use these two names I tend to agree with the answer proposed and set up an Nginx proxy host, then create Route 53 record of type A: "ui.example.com" = Nginx elastic IP and then configure Nginx to forward or redirect "/" to your S3 bucket (or better yet a Cloudfront distribution of it) and "/api" to your ELB. Here's an example Nginx config that could be used: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34345883/472153

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try proposed solution with Nginx proxy. Do I need to create additional EC2 instance for my Nginx proxy host ? And one more question about performance - will introducing of Nginx lead to performance degradation of the system (response time, degradation benefits of CDN) ?

Comment: and do I need NGINX Plus or pure Nginx ?

Comment: Regular Nginx will work fine. Running it on a separate server depends on things like the server size, how much traffic you are getting, etc. I can't tell you the answer to that. Nginx is very fast and lightweight, it shouldn't create any noticeable performance degradation if configured correctly. It can actually improve site performance when serving static files or if used to cache responses.